# bash variable in string substitution

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I am trying to do string substitution in bash, want to understand it better.

I crafted a success case like this:

```
a=abc_de_f
var=$a
echo ${var//_/-}
```

outout is `abc-de-f`. This works.

However, the following script fails:

```
a=abc_de_f
echo ${$a//_/-}
```

The error message is `${$a//_/-}: bad substitution`.
It seems like related to how we can use a variable in substitution. Why this fails? How bash handles variables in this case?

Also, what is the best practice to handle escape characters in bash string substitution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the second case, you don't need the second `$` as `a` is the string.

```
a=abc_de_f
echo ${a//_/-}
```

If you wanted to add a level of [indirection](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html), you can use `!` before the variable as in

```
a=abc_de_f
b=a
echo ${b//_/-}
```

will output `a`, while

```
echo ${!b//_/-}
```

will output `abc-de-f`.

See [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting) for a discussion on the art of escaping in BASH

Comment: Upvoted for linking to wiki.bash-hackers.org, where I found the solution to my problem. Thank you!!!